# Write a File to a password protected shared path using JCIFS

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jcifs

I am new to JCIFS and I am trying to write (create new) a file in a password protected shared path using JCIFS. The below code will give you an overview on what and how I am trying to achieve it.

```
    String user = "myUserId";
    String pass ="myPassword#";
    String path = "smb:\\\\<<My Host>>\\Hag\\To GC\\Tester\\test.txt";
    NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("<<My Domain>>",user, pass);
    SmbFile smbFile = new SmbFile(path,auth);
    SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);
    smbfos.write("Testing JCFIC".getBytes());
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException` at
`SmbFileOutputStream smbfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(smbFile);`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at jcifs.smb.ServerMessageBlock.writeString(ServerMessageBlock.java:213)
at jcifs.smb.ServerMessageBlock.writeString(ServerMessageBlock.java:202)
at jcifs.smb.SmbComNTCreateAndX.writeBytesWireFormat(SmbComNTCreateAndX.java:170)
at jcifs.smb.AndXServerMessageBlock.writeAndXWireFormat(AndXServerMessageBlock.java:101)
at jcifs.smb.AndXServerMessageBlock.encode(AndXServerMessageBlock.java:65)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.doSend(SmbTransport.java:439)
at jcifs.util.transport.Transport.sendrecv(Transport.java:67)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:655)
at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:238)
at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.send(SmbTree.java:119)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.send(SmbFile.java:775)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open0(SmbFile.java:989)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.open(SmbFile.java:1006)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:142)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:97)
at jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream.<init>(SmbFileOutputStream.java:67)
at com.labcorp.efone.utility.Tester.main(Tester.java:35)
```

please see below the  when executing the above program. Please let me know what I am missing and guide me to a right direction.

Comment: Could you please add the full stack trace to the question?

Comment: So something is null in line 213 of ServerMessageBlock.java. I would look up the code and see what is missing, but we need the exact jcifs-version you are using. Which one is it?

Comment: The two variables I see there in one version of the code point to likely the path you specify, which is clearly not null, or some internal buffer. But following the up in the code, I get stuck at some point, because the stack trace does not fit the code anymore.

Comment: Out of curiosity have you tried using smb://.... using forward slashes instead of back slashes?

Comment: yeah.. I ahve tried using forward slash.. still same issue persists

Comment: The version of JCIFS im using is "jcifs-1.3.17". I believe its not a version issue. Please suggest